# How do I get raw form data in Laravel?

Tags: php, http, laravel, put

I have a script that is trying to send data to my site using HTTP [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). Normally, I would just retrieve it by reading from the input stream with `file_get_contents('php://input')`. However, when I try that with Laravel, I don't get anything! Why not? How do I read the raw input data?

Answer (score 42):

Laravel intercepts all input. If you're using PHP prior to 5.6, the `php://input` stream can only be read once. This means that you need to get the data from the framework. You can do this by accessing the `getContent` method on the `Request` instance, like this:

```
$content = Request::getContent(); // Using Request facade
     /* or */ 
$content = $request->getContent(); // If you already have a Request instance
                                   // lying around, from say the controller
```

Since `Illuminate\Request` extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`, and `getContent` is defined here: http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getContent

Comment: I think theoretically you shouldn't need to get the instance, but can just use the facade directly: `Request::getContent();`

Comment: I'm trying to send an XML into the Laravel and used this function and it is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ```$content = request()->getContent();``` also works.

Comment: The link is half-broken. It redirects to GitHub and the anchor `#method_getContent` does not work at all. [#L1478](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1478) does work, but I don't know how stable it is (or if it is the intended one).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Request::json($key, $default);` to return the value of a specific key in the JSON payload.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update for latest Laravel (I'm using Laravel 5.8)

You may encounter an error when using `Request::getContent();`, because the latest Symfony Request module (which underlie Laravel's Request module) no longer provides `getContent` as a static method. Instead I use `Request::createFromGlobals()->getContent();`.

Reference: *[Accessing Request Data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data)*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).